# apply Gradient descent on dataset

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset (on CSV file) and I want to apply on it the Gradient descent with Python
 I do not how I can read my dataset on this code.

I want to know the accuracy of this dataset and visualize it.

I try a lot but no answer .. the code is running correctly but how I can make the code to read my dataset.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
import numpy as np
import argparse


def sigmoid_activation(x):
    return 1.0 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-e", "--epochs", type=float, default=100,
                help="# of epochs")
ap.add_argument("-a", "--alpha", type=float, default=0.01,
                help="learning rate")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

(X, y) = make_blobs(n_samples=250, n_features=2, centers=2, cluster_std=1.05, random_state=20)
X = np.c_[np.ones((X.shape[0])), X]
print("[INFO] starting training...")
W = np.random.uniform(size=(X.shape[1],))
lossHistory = []

for data in np.arange(0, args["epochs"]):
    preds = sigmoid_activation(X.dot(W))
    error = preds - y
    loss = np.sum(error ** 2)
    lossHistory.append(loss)
    print("[INFO] epoch #{}, loss={:.7f}".format(data + 1, loss))

gradient = X.T.dot(error) / X.shape[0]
W += -args["alpha"] * gradient

for i in np.random.choice(250, 10):
    activation = sigmoid_activation(X[i].dot(W))
    label = 0 if activation < 0.5 else 1
    print("activation={:.4f}; predicted_label={}, true_label={}".format(activation, label, y[i]))

Y = (-W[0] - (W[1] * X)) / W[2]

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X[:, 1], X[:, 2], marker="o", c=y)
plt.plot(X, Y, "r-")

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(0, args["epochs"]), lossHistory)
fig.suptitle("Training Loss")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you should first format your code, Python is sensitive to indention so you need to make it clear because it is hard for us to guess the indentations.

Comment: okay, I know that I edit now the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can read a CSV file (named `foo.csv` for example) using the following:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('foo.csv', delimiter=",")
X = data[:,:2]
y = data[:, 2]
```

The code above assumes 2 features in the first two columns and `y` as the third column.

Comment: where i can put this code to get the right code and correct output, please

Comment: replace the above code with the line in your code which starts with `(X, y)`

Comment: do you mean i replace the above code with this line?  (X, y) = make_blobs(n_samples=250, n_features=2, centers=2, cluster_std=1.05, random_state=20) .           is that give the right answer?

Comment: provided that you use the right file name and right data (2 feature and the dependent variable at the end) yes, it should give the right answer

Comment: can you please clear to me what do you mean here (2 feature and the dependent variable at the end) ?? and where exactly put it in code I am a newer in python this is my first time to develop in python